# If the second moments are uniformly bounded, does $Y_n$ converge in $L^2$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, expectation

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a pairwise uncorrelated sequence of random variables such that there exists a fixed constant $c>0$ such that $E(X_n^2)\leq c$ for all $n\geq1$. Does it imply that for any $\alpha>0.5$, $Y_n=\dfrac{1}{n^\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\xrightarrow{L^2}0?$

Well, for $\alpha>1$ I have found the result is true. My working is as follows:

$$E(\dfrac{1}{n^\alpha}\sum_{k=1}^nX_k)^2$$$$=\dfrac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}E(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2+\sum_{i\neq j}X_iX_j)$$

Now $$E(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2)\leq nc$$

Also $$E(X_iX_j)\leq\sqrt{E(X_i^2)E(X_j^2)}\leq c$$

So $$\dfrac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}E(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k^2+\sum_{i\neq j}X_iX_j)^2\leq\dfrac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}(nc+n(n-1)c)=n^{2-2\alpha}c$$

The above converges to $0$ iff $2-2\alpha<0\iff\alpha>1$.

What happens when $\alpha\in(\dfrac{1}{2},1]$?

Please note that I have not used the zero correlation condition. I cannot figure out how we can apply it.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to your question is that it doesn't converge to zero for $\alpha \leq 1$.  Consider the case $\alpha = 1$.  This is the [Law of Large Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers).  If your random variables were iid then that converges to the mean which may not be zero.  For $\alpha > 1/2$ we have the sum being even larger.  And in the case $\alpha = 1/2$ (which you didn't ask about) we have the central limit theorem.

Comment: Silly of me not to realize these simple facts. How does $\alpha=0.5$ imply the Central Limit Theorem?

Comment: You would need the means to be zero for the limit to exist, but the CLT says just that, if the $X_i$ are iid, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \sum_i X_i \rightarrow N$ where $N$ is a normal distribution.  I'm wondering if there wasn't supposed to be an additional requirement that your random variables have zero mean.

Comment: No, there is no further assumption on the mean.